# How can i create Cassanda structure like Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, cassandra

I have story project in php & mysql, big data, many web services , ...
I want create new version in node & cassandra,
I need some features,
1.Speed & performance for clients
2.create big reports from many tables

question 1: integrate from mysql to cassandra is true or false?
question 2: best practice for create products and groups table?

in mysql:

```
tblproducts
  id,
  gid,
  name,
  ...
tblgroups
  id,
  name,
```

how can better design in cassandra?
create 2 table in cassandra too? or any idea better than?

Answer (score 2):

Table structure in Cassandra is designed around queries that you're planning to execute for your users. Cassandra shines when you're querying data by the primary key (or at least by partition key) - these requests are served by the one or few nodes.  Because you may have multiple query types, you'll need to denormalize your data into multiple tables, duplicating the data.   Only in this case you'll get adequate performance.  And reporting on the data is usually done by tools like Apache Spark, using the [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/).

Before proceed with table design, I recommend to take the DS220 course on data modeling at [DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/), and/or grab a free copy of [Cassandra. The Definitive Guide](https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide) book that has good chapter on the data modeling.